# Laravel 5 - private package - How to use in other projects

Tags: laravel, composer-php, gitlab

I cannot find any information on how I can do this.

i have created a small package in laravel. This package is just a simple basic package that I want to use in other laravel projects that I will be creating.

The package is in a repo stored on Gitlab and I cannot for the life of me find how it's possible to link this within a composer file for another project? I believe I will have to give the URL for the repository but is there anywhere I can see examples of this?

Answer (score 0):

From the Composer Documentation: [Loading a package from a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#vcs)

```
  {
      "repositories": [
          {
              "type": "vcs",
              "url": "https://github.com/igorw/monolog"
          }
      ],
      "require": {
          "monolog/monolog": "dev-bugfix"
      }
  }
```